# to understand something "under"/"by" something

Tags: british-english, particles

Is the following correct:

> The pieces are based on the concept of imperfect reconstruction. **By imperfect reconstruction, I understand** a strategy that produces repetitions which ...

The dictionaries and Google-translate are failing me here.

Or should I say

> The pieces are based on the concept of imperfect reconstruction. **Under imperfect reconstruction, I understand** a strategy that produces repetitions which ...

(this sounds like a wrong translation from German to me).

Or should I say

> The pieces are based on the concept of imperfect reconstruction. **Imperfect reconstruction I understand as** a strategy that produces repetitions which ...

Comment: "understand" refers to your own comprehension of the term "imperfect reconstruction" defined by another author. If its your own definition, replace "understand" by "mean".

Comment: @Graffito yes, it's my own definition, "mean" thus makes sense, too. This come from German "etwas unter etwas verstehen", where "verstehen" in this context is probably to mean rather than to understand.

Comment: Besides the understand/mean issue, the first formulation accurately reflects your thinking and sounds the best in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1. **By imperfect reconstruction** describes the process by which you're coming to understand a strategy.

**Under imperfect reconstruction** suggests that you yourself are being imperfectly reconstructed, or you're operating under a set of rules called "Imperfect reconstruction".

**Imperfect reconstruction I understand as** suggests that it is imperfect reconstruction itself that is the strategy.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so number two is definitely wrong, number three seems right.

Comment: Note that _by_ would be right with certain other words, like _mean_, but doesn't work very well with _understand_. “By ‘imperfect reconstruction’ I mean a strategy that…” is perfectly fine and idiomatic.